# Pull most recent records for distinct users in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

The database is something like this:

```
id testID date
1  100    10/12/2012
2  100    10/13/2012
3  102    10/14/2012
```

Let's call this database "Test"

I want the output to be an ActiveRecord:Relation that contains

```
id testID date
2  100    10-13-2012
3  102    10-14-2012
```

I know how to get the results as an array, as following:

```
result = []
testIDList = Test.uniq.pluck(:testID)
testIDList.each do |tID|
    result = result + Test.where(:testID => tID).order('date DESC').limit(1)
end
```

In this case, result is an array of ActiveRecord:Relation
But I want result to be an ActiveRecord:Relation, I tried to use merge no success.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   result = Test.order(:date).group(:testID)
```

Comment: Test.order(:date) works, but with .group(:testID) it failed. I think it doesn't know how to group them together.

Comment: u sure the name of the field is testID only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = Test.where(:testID => testIDList)
             .select("max(`date`) as recent_date").group(:testID)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Test.where(:testID => testIDList) is same as Test. .select("max(`date`) as recent_date") failed as well. :(